# cancelling async task using progress bar causes targetinvocationexception error using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, async-await, progress-bar, cancellationtokensource

I am trying to load a datatable async so that the UI remains responsive.  I've used the dt.RowChanged event to handle reporting progress back to the progress bar and label.  But when the Stop button is clicked, it causes the following error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll.

I'm not sure how to find my way around this issue.  Any guidance is appreciated. The following is code from sample project using AdventureWorks DB

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Class AsyncProgressCancel
    Public strConnectionString As String = "data source=010XXX01;initial catalog=AdventureWorks2012;integrated security=SSPI;"
    Private dt As DataTable
    Private ds As DataSet
    Dim dataset
    Dim RecordCount As Integer = 1000000
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim myProgress As Progress(Of Integer)
    Private Delegate Sub AsyncDelegate(ByVal value As Integer)
    Private ProgressUpdater As New AsyncDelegate(AddressOf UpdateProgress)
    Private TargetCounter As Integer = 1000
    Private cts As CancellationTokenSource
    Private Cancelled As Boolean

    Private Sub AsyncProgressCancel_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        ProgressBar1.Visible = False
        lblProgress.Visible = False
        btnStop.Enabled = False
    End Sub
    Private Async Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click


        btnStart.Enabled = False
        btnStop.Enabled = True
        Cancelled = False

        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = RecordCount
        ProgressBar1.Visible = True
        lblProgress.Visible = True
        DataGridView1.Enabled = False
        cts = New CancellationTokenSource()

        Try
            Dim completed As Boolean = Await LoadDataAsync(myProgress, cts.Token)

        Catch ex As OperationCanceledException
            lblProgress.Text = "Retrieve cancelled."
            DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
            DataGridView1.Enabled = True
            btnStop.Enabled = False
            btnStart.Enabled = True
            ProgressBar1.Visible = False
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex)
        End Try

    End Sub
    Private Sub UpdateProgress(ByVal value As Integer)

        If Cancelled = True Then
            cts.Cancel()
        Else
            If ProgressBar1.InvokeRequired Then
                ProgressBar1.Invoke(ProgressUpdater, New Object() {value})
            ElseIf value > ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
                value = ProgressBar1.Maximum
                ProgressBar1.Value = value
            End If

            lblProgress.Text = Math.Round((value / RecordCount) * 100).ToString & "% complete"      '"Step Number: " & myInt.ToString
            ProgressBar1.Value = value

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Async Function LoadDataAsync(ByVal myProgress As IProgress(Of Integer), token As CancellationToken) As Task(Of Boolean)

        Dim comSQL As SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Dim strSQL As String
        Dim da As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim ReturnValue As Boolean


        Try
            DataGridView1.Enabled = Await Task(Of Boolean).Run(Function()
                                                                   Using conn As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(strConnectionString)
                                                                       conn.Open()

                                                                       strSQL = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1000000 PRODUCTION.PRODUCT.* FROM sales.SalesOrderDetail CROSS JOIN production.Product) A"
                                                                       comSQL = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
                                                                       da = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(comSQL)

                                                                       AddHandler dt.RowChanged, Sub(obj, e)

                                                                                                     If e.Action.Add Then
                                                                                                         Counter = obj.Rows.Count

                                                                                                         If Counter > RecordCount Then
                                                                                                             Counter = RecordCount
                                                                                                         Else
                                                                                                             Counter = Counter + 1        ' Math.Ceiling(0.1 * RecordCount)
                                                                                                         End If
                                                                                                     End If

                                                                                                     If token.IsCancellationRequested = True Then
                                                                                                         token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()


                                                                                                     Else
                                                                                                         If Counter = TargetCounter Then
                                                                                                             UpdateProgress(Counter)
                                                                                                             TargetCounter = TargetCounter + 1000
                                                                                                         End If
                                                                                                     End If
                                                                                                 End Sub


                                                                       If Counter > 0 Then
                                                                           myProgress.Report(Counter)
                                                                       End If



                                                                       da.Fill(dt)
                                                                       dataset = dt

                                                                       ReturnValue = True

                                                                       Return ReturnValue
                                                                   End Using
                                                               End Function, token)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex)
        End Try

    End Function

    Private Sub btnStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStop.Click
        Try
            If Not cts Is Nothing Then
                cts.Cancel()    
            End If    
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex)
        End Try    
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Cancelling a task *does* raise that exception. In fact, you *are* requesting that exception with `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`. Your code though has more serious bugs. First of all, you are using `Task.Run` to fake asynchronous execution instead of using one of the asynchronous methods like `ExecuteReaderAsync`.

Comment: Second bug, you are trying to load 100K rows, into a *datatable*, which is a problem in itself. You can't display 100K rows so why load it? If you want to transfer the data to another location, just *don't* use a DataTable, use a reader to read the data and copy it to the target. Finally, if you want to process 100K rows, why don't you do it on the *server*? It will be faster than trying to work on the client without the benefit of indexes or caching

Comment: *Why* are you trying to load 100K rows on the client at all? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Whatever it is, there are faster and easier ways to do it

Comment: Unfortunately I'm new to the async await functionality and this is my first go at it.  So any fixes to my code would be appreciated.  The reason why we're bringing down the 'wall of data' is because it's a business requirement.  We are combining SQL databases from multiple locations for  a region and there's a request to be able to be able to view all records across all locations in a grid view and filter from there like an excel spreadsheet.  We (developers) have been trying to move them to using more of data warehouse reporting solution, but have been vetoed.

Comment: No customer is going to require loading useless data in the slowest way possible. That's how analysts or developers interpret the *actual* requirement. If the requirement is "Create an Excel sheet of 100K rows", use an SSIS package to do that in a few clicks. You can schedule the package to run periodically and generate whatever the user wants, or even execute it from code. Or use a reader and EPPlus. Why would you ever use a grid to generate an Excel sheet?

Comment: Also, *why* generate such a sheet? No business user is going to say "Give me all the data so I can do the work of the database by hand". They'll say "OK, if you can't generate a report, at least extract the data so I can do it". An Excel sheet with a PowerQuery data source that loads data from the database will actually be *faster* than generating a sheet on the fly

Comment: I don't mean that they're going to use it to export to excel - they want the wall of data and filter it down like they would be able to in excel except within the application grid view.  The manager is stuck on not wanting the user to have to go outside the application to get the data they want to see.  We're pretty much jumping through hoops to get the users what they want.

Comment: You had mentioned previously about why not use ExecuteReaderAsync - I'm not really familiar on it's use.  Is it something that you could explain?  Or point me in the right direction on the proper use of async calls for what I'm trying to do?